# How can I play an audio file in mobile phones?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a jQuery statement where I call a created file to be played. The thing is that it is correctly played in the pc but when I try to execute it in the mobile phone I can hear nothing and the volume is at maximum.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        audioElement.setAttribute('src', './static/audio/welcome.mp3');
        audioElement.play();
    })
</script>
```

I am playing it on Safari and if I embed the code into a button it works when I press it but is there anyway I can play it when the DOM is loaded?

Answer (score -1):

Could you tell me what browser did you try it please? here is an old post where the guy had the same problem :

[Link for jquery music mobile](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/audio-not-playing-in-the-mobile-works-only-in-desktop-navigator)

Comment: This is not an answer. Please see [answer] and take the [tour].

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.